# Fibonacci summation

Tags: number-theory, summation, fibonacci-numbers, pi, harmonic-numbers

Can anyone help me to prove the following relation.

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_{2k}H^{(2)}_{k-1}}{k^2\binom{2k}{k}}=\frac{2\pi^4}{375\sqrt{5}}$$
>   I was studying recently about Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.

And I came through the above relationship. I tried applying golden ratio but nothing works. 
Symbols have their usual meanings.

Comment: This is nice! Perhaps someone can answer it !! :)

Comment: Let me bump this..

Comment: Where did you read the stuff, that should be a nice read! could you please share?

Comment: Since it is an older post, I didn't remember exactly. I have read it in research papers regarding Fibonacci and lucas numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is well known that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k^{2}\dbinom{2k}{k}}H_{k-1}^{\left(2\right)}=\frac{2\arcsin^{4}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{3},\,\left|x\right|\leq2$$ (see [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume2007/019381.pdf) or [here](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan%27s%20Notebooks%20I.pdf) for a proof), then from the [Binet formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) we get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_{2n}}{k^{2}\dbinom{2k}{k}}H_{k-1}^{\left(2\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{2n}}{2^{2n}k^{2}\dbinom{2k}{k}}H_{k-1}^{\left(2\right)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{2n}}{2^{2n}k^{2}\dbinom{2k}{k}}H_{k-1}^{\left(2\right)}$$ $$=\frac{2\arcsin^{4}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)}{3\sqrt{5}}-\frac{2\arcsin^{4}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)}{3\sqrt{5}}=\color{red}{\frac{2\pi^{4}}{375\sqrt{5}}}.$$